# Three.js RGB Cube with vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js, rgb

I try to do a RGB cube in Three.js, but i must use a vertices, no textures. I look at some tutorials, but my code does not work, can I ask for advice? Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/yjru14q3/

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();

        geom.vertices = vertices;
        geom.vertexColors = colors;
        var colors = [];
        colors[0] = new THREE.Color( 0, 0, 0 );
        ....
        var vertices = [];
        vertices[0] = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
        ....
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
            vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide, // in case we go inside the cube
        });

        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
        scene.add(cube);
```

Comment: You can use box geometry - [link to box geometry docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Geometries/BoxGeometry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using of `geometry.colors[]` works with `vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors` when you use the geometry for `THREE.Points()`.

[image]

If you want to apply vertex colors for faces' vertices of `THREE.Mesh()`, then it's better to follow [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors):

```
var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var faceIndices = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var vertexIndex, point;
geom.faces.forEach(function(face) { // loop through faces
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    vertexIndex = face[ faceIndices[ i ] ]; // get the face's vertex's index
    point = geom.vertices[vertexIndex]; // knowing the index, find the vertex in array of vertices
    color = new THREE.Color( // create a color
      point.x + 0.5, //apply xyz as rgb
      point.y + 0.5,
      point.z + 0.5
    );
    face.vertexColors[ i ] = color; //store the color in the face's vertexColors array
  }
});

var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
scene.add(cube);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/q7pn12tt/) example